# Process task abnormally terminated with exit code (PM_ASSERT_ERROR)

Tags: c++, bada, samsung-mobile

The application is crashing when i move back from a child form to parent form. It is giving

**Process task abnormally terminated with exit code (PM_ASSERT_ERROR)**

**Crashed Appl Task Call stack**

I think that if some thread is running in child form, the above crash occurs.
For EX: In the child form, i am downloading images using **DecodeUrl()**. when i go back to parent form, i am deallocating all the memory assigned for different objects and then i am removing the child form from app control, I think the image download thread is still active and causing the crash. Any idea how to handle this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to remove UI controls explicitly. The framework does that for you.